# Redirect Java Script ou HTML

Tags: javascript, java, html

Gostaria de estar fazendo o mesmo redirecionamento baseado na localização do usuario. tem essa possibilidade?

ex: se ele estiver no Brasil permanece no site. se ele for de outro pais é redirecionado automaticamente para outro site.

Obrigado

Answer (score 1):

Existe sim essa possibilidade Bernardo :). Você pode utilizar algum serviço que já te fornecesse essa informação como esses por exemplo:

- [Maxmind](https://www.maxmind.com)
- [Ipinfo](https://ipinfo.io/)
- [ipstack](https://ipstack.com/product) (Plano grátis para até 10.000 consultas/mes)
- [ipgeolocation](https://ipgeolocation.io/pricing) (Plano grátis para até 50.000 consultas/mes)

Para esses 4, você precisa pagar uma taxa pelas consultas dependendo do plano. Uma alternativa gratuita é o [ip-api](http://ip-api.com/). Para testar sua localização, acesse a url abaixo no seu browser:

```
http://ip-api.com/json
```

No seu site, você vai precisa desse trecho de código bem antes do fechamento da tag body:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
     $.get({
         url:'http://ip-api.com/json', 
         timeout: 5000
     }).then(
         //Funcao de sucesso
         function success(response) {
            if(!response.country === "Brazil") {
                //Caso sim, redireciona para outra url
                window.location.href = "https://www.nytimes.com/";
             }
         }, 
         //Funcao de erro
         function fail(data, status) {
            //Continua no site em portugues
         }
      );
 });
```

Será necessário ter importado o [jQuery](https://code.jquery.com/). Lembrando que como é um servico gratuito, você pode sofrer intermitência/lentidão para as chamadas. Detalhes: os nomes dos países são retornados em inglês.

Comment: Boa noite, tudo bem? Infelizmente esse codigo não esta dando certo. Fiz o cadastro no " ipgeolocation " e peguei a chave de ativação para implementar o mesmo, mesmo assim não funciona. :/

Answer (score 0):

Bernardo, as únicas modificações necessárias nesse código, é a URL que você deve utilizar e o parâmetro que retorna o nome do país. A url deve seguir o seguinte padrão: `https://api.ipgeolocation.io/ipgeo?apiKey=API_KEY`, onde **API_KEY** deve ser substituido pelo valor que se encontra no seu dashboard da ferramenta na seção **"Your API Key"**. O campo que te devolve o nome do país, muda para **country_name**.  Dessa forma, o código acima para o *ipgeolocation* fica:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $.get({
            url:'https://api.ipgeolocation.io/ipgeo?apiKey=1234567890', 
            timeout: 5000
        }).then(
            //Funcao de sucesso
            function success(response) {
                if(!response.country_name === "Brazil") {
                    //Caso sim, redireciona para outra url
                    window.location.href = "https://www.nytimes.com/";
                }
            }, 
            //Funcao de erro
            function fail(data, status) {
                //Continua no site em portugues
            }
        );
    });
</script>`
```